# Upgrading to Rails 3.2.19

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, upgrade

I have a Rails app that is still running 3.2.14 and I want to get on the latest stable branch of the 3.2.x series which would be 3.2.19 I believe.  Short of just blindly doing a bundle update rails, what should I be on the lookout for jumping from 3.2.14 to 3.2.19?  I know there are some security fixes, but anything major I should watch for?

Obviously I'll do this in my development environment first before pushing to production, but I want to get to 3.2.19 quickly.

Any feedback or comments that might prove useful?

Comment: it might be helpful to browse [compare](https://github.com/rails/rails/compare/v3.2.14...v3.2.19)

Comment: Thanks, I'm doing that today to look for things that might possibly break.